# Task runner explorer doesn't save bindings in VS2013

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2013, gulp, task-runner-explorer

My IDE is VS2013 with task runner explorer extension. How can i save task binding (like this task should run on solution open) so that i could share this binding settings with my team (via any version control system)? I want to avoid setting up everything manually on each PC and maintain those bindings for new tasks later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out if you bind one of your tasks to all events and reopen solution you'll see in first line of your gulpfile.js something like this:

```
/// <vs BeforeBuild='task_name' AfterBuild='task_name' Clean='task_name' SolutionOpened='task_name' />
var gulp = require('gulp');
// other gulp stuff ...
```

If you want to assign two or more tasks to one event just add them to corresponding event like this

```
/// <vs AfterBuild='task_1, task_2, task_3' />
```